# Object has been deleted or invalidated realm

Tags: swift, realm

I have this class inherit from `Object`:

```
class Location: Object {
    dynamic var id: String = ""
    dynamic var name: String = ""

    override class func primaryKey() -> String {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

This class is used as an instance inside my manager like this:

```
class LocationServiceAPI {

    fileprivate var _location: Location?
    var location: Location? {
        get {
            if _location == nil {
                let realm = try! Realm()
                _location = realm.objects(Location.self).first
            }
            return _location
        }
        set {
            let realm = try! Realm()

            if let newValue = newValue {
                // delete previous locations
                let locations = realm.objects(Location.self)
                try! realm.write {
                    realm.delete(locations)
                }

                // store new location
                try! realm.write {
                    realm.add(newValue, update: true)
                    _location = newValue
                }
            } else {
                let locations = realm.objects(Location.self)
                try! realm.write {
                    realm.delete(locations)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So whenever I get a location I delete the old one (new and old locations could be identical) and replace it with the new one, then I used the `newValue` as new value for the property `_location` but whenever I try to access the `location` it gives me 'Object has been deleted or invalidated'.

I am really confused since `location` will hold the value passed from the setter but not the realm!!

Note: If I stop the deleting then It will work fine.

Comment: How do you delete the discarded location ? 
Second question : Do you use threads ?

Comment: @bogdanf I have updated my answer with the deletion part.

Comment: So you use just one `Location` object in your entire app (you delete all `Location` objects in your database so I assume you just have one). Why don't you store it in NSUserDefaults, there is really no need for a database to store just one object :-)

Now, if you absolutely need to keep it in Realm, just save/retrieve it directly from the DB like I've shown you in my response, there is really, really no need to cache it in a variable in your LocationServicesAPI class.

Answer (score 1):

The `Object has been deleted or invalidated` error will occur if an object has been deleted from a Realm, but you subsequently try and access a stored property of an instance of that object that your code was hanging onto since before the deletion.

You'll need to examine your logic paths and make sure there's no way you're deleting the location object, and not subsequently updating the `_location` property. There's no mention of deleting the object in the sample code you've provided, but your `if let newValue = newValue` line of code would mean that `_location` wouldn't actually get cleared if you passed in `nil`.

Finally, it's possible to manually check if an object has been deleted from a Realm by calling `_location.invalidated`, so if this happens a lot, it might be a good idea to include some extra checks in your code as well.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing really anything about your app and your design choices, it looks like you're trying to avoid reading/writing to the DB too often by caching the location property. Unless you're working with tons of `LocationServiceAPI` objects it shouldn't be a real performance penalty to actually read/write directly in the DB, like this :

```
class LocationServiceAPI {

    var location: Location? {
        get {
            let realm = try! Realm()
            return realm.objects(Location.self).first
        }
        set {
           let realm = try! Realm()
           if let newValue = newValue {
              // store new location
              try! realm.write {
                  realm.add(newValue, update: true)
              }
           } else {
              // delete the record from Realm
              ...
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, I would in general avoid keeping Realm objects along for longer periods, I don't say it's not possible but in general it leads to issues like you've experienced (especially if do multi-threading). In most cases I'd rather fetch the object from DB, use it, change it and save it back in the DB asap. If keeping references to specific records in the DB is necessary I'd rather keep the id and re-fetch it when I need it.